# What is a word that is stronger than beautiful but not quite perfect?

Tags: single-word-requests

When we see women, sometimes we say they are average looking, above-average looking, pretty, beautiful, and perfect. Assuming we rate the attractiveness of women out of 100, what is a word that means almost perfect but is not perfect. For example, what if we felt an attraction of 97 out of 100 for Jane Doe? If beautiful was an 80-89 and perfect is 100. What word would I use to describe those who are believed to have a rating of 90-99? Currently, I have only thought of near-perfect/almost perfect, but I was wondering if there was a single word that described that phrase. When doing a google search for synonyms of beautiful, things like gorgeous, pretty, prepossessed, charming, delightful, handsome, good-looking, and charming come up. For me, gorgeous and prepossessed is equal to or less than beautiful. Also I don't really like the word, gorgeous. Charming and delightful can be attributed towards women, but I usually think of them as gender-neutral and about their personality exclusively. Handsome and good-looking are usually attributed to males (not sure about good-looking but definitely handsome). Preferably, this word should usually relate to women.

Comment: Eh ... Do what?

Comment: How about *near-perfect* or *all but perfect*?

Comment: Hmm but that just seems to be a way to say almost perfect. Is there a single word for that? Also it seems kind of redundant to use perfect again, but that is just me personally.

Comment: And where are you on the scale?

Comment: [satisficed](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&es_sm=91&q=satisficed)? I presume you are writing a cultural criticism essay for The Atlantic, suggesting a new scoring method for beauty because with so many women to choose from, 1 through 10 is not precise enough for machine learning algorithms?

Comment: When describing something subjectively as near perfect, I would commonly say *perfect to **me***.

Comment: The first word I thought of when I saw this question was “transcendent”.  One might object that it is too general; i.e., applicable to attributes other than appearance/beauty.  Definitions of “transcendent” include such words as [exceptional](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/transcendent), [preeminent, supreme](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=transcendent), [unparalleled, unique, extraordinary and superior](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transcendent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of a single word for near-perfect, but there are many that describe a beautiful woman.

Elegant, gorgeous, ideal, lovely, stunning, radiant, exquisite, fair, fetching, delicate, divine, dazzling, enticing, enthralling, magnificent, resplendent, mesmerizing, charming, captivating, adorable, alluring.

From @Graffito: Superb, majestic, marvelous, sumptuous, admirable

You could always describe her many appealing features in succession followed by a single imperfection to convey the idea better. Or preface one of the listed words with near-*

Hope this helps!

Comment: ["Stop Trying to Make Fetch Happen"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pubd-spHN-0)

Comment: I chose yours because I like ideal better than all the rest suggested.

Comment: @user1470901- just a comment, *ideal* just doesn’t have the gravitas that even *beautiful* has. “She is the ideal girl” might mean she has the right mix of fun, intelligence, beauty, money, etc.  and that probably doesn’t mean she scores 100 in each of those categories. *near-perfect* or *nearly-perfect* seem much more descriptive to me.

Answer (score 7):

I always liked exquisite,  that would seem to be in the ballpark

Comment: Along with perhaps sublime, I think this is the winner  :)

Answer (score 2):

In its list, Charles W didn't mention **superb**, **majestic**, **marvellous**, **sumptuous** or **admirable**

Comment: Thanks for the terms, but I think I like near-ideal best.

Answer (score 0):

I have generally seen *attractive* used to express what you explained.  It means that the woman is not Vogue magazine material, but all the aspects come together to give the desired effect.  If you want to lean towards the 99 end of your range, you could say "extremely attractive".  I think "breathtakingly attractive" would be right at 99.

Comment: This question has been closed as (primarily) opinion-based, and your answer illustrates that.  IMHO, “attractive” is a much ***weaker*** word than “beautiful”.  For example, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attractive) defines “attractive” as “pleasant to look at”, which is fairly wishy-washy.  I consider “attractive” to be approximately on par with “pretty” (which is milder than “beautiful”).

Answer (score 0):

Pulchritudinous, from the Latin pulchra meaning 'beautiful'

For the 'near-perfect' aspect, I'd say something like "stellar"

Answer (score 0):

***[Sublime](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sublime)***

> adjective:
>
> Of *very great* excellence or beauty.

(Oxford Dictionary)